# JavaScript embedded function within function

Tags: javascript

I came across this example on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) and it doesn't work as described:

```
function makePerson(first, last) {
    return {
        first: first,
        last: last,
        fullName: function() {
            return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
        },
        fullNameReversed: function() {
            return this.last + ', ' + this.first;
        }
    }
}

Example Call:
> s = makePerson("Simon", "Willison")
> s.fullName()
Simon Willison
> s.fullNameReversed()
Willison, Simon
```

The article was written in 2006, and in both IE10 and Chrome 26, it just displays the literal code for the fullName and fullNameReversed functions. Is this functionality no longer working for modern browsers?

Comment: That code does work. Maybe you forgot the calling parentheses when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it appears I forgot the calling parentheses. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've missed out the parentheses from the end of your function call.

Try

```
s.fullName();
```

instead of

```
s.fullName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears to work just fine on chromium v25

Javascript

```
function makePerson(first, last) {
    return {
        first: first,
        last: last,
        fullName: function() {
            return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
        },
        fullNameReversed: function() {
            return this.last + ', ' + this.first;
        }
    }
}

var s = makePerson("Simon", "Willison");
console.log(s.fullName());
console.log(s.fullNameReversed());
```

Output

```
Simon Willison
Willison, Simon
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9nSta/)

Answer (score 1):

If you receive the code for the function, it is probably because you call the function like `s.fullName` and not `s.fullName()` (You are missing the parenthesis)